# What are the coefficients of linear combinations of two edges of a pentagon to get to the other unknown two vertices

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that we know three vertices of a pentagon: $v_0=(0,0,0)$, $v_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, and $v_2=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$, such that $|v_1|=|v_2|=1$, and the angle between $v_1$ and $v_2$ is $108^{\circ}$. How to find the other vertices of the pentagon using linear algebra. That is, any vector on the plane spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$ is a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$. In particular $v_3 = \alpha_3 v_1 + \beta_3 v_2$, and $v_4=\alpha_4 v_1 + \beta_4 v_2$.  Find $\alpha_3, \alpha_4, \beta_3, \beta_4$, such that $v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ are the five vertices of a pentagon. Is there an easy way to do this without posting 10 equations with 10 unknowns?

Are $\alpha_3$ and $\alpha_4$ invariant? They should, since they do not depend on any coordinate system. So if we do this the $(x,y,0)$ plane it is easier and it should work, if that is the case $\alpha_3$ and $\alpha_4$ are constants, right?

I has been indicated that my question might have been solved in the link:
[Finding vertices of regular polygon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267646/finding-vertices-of-regular-polygon)

That is not the case. My question is very specific to a pentagon and I am looking for 2 Coefficients. Rotation matrices such as 
\begin{eqnarray}
\left (
  \begin{array}{cc}
     \cos \theta & - \sin \theta \\
      \sin \theta & \cos \theta
  \end{array}
  \right ) 
\end{eqnarray}

are totally useless here. The question is in the context of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Not even 3D rotation matrices with the matrix above as a minor. How would you find the other vertices of a pentagon knowing that two  edges are $(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ and $(b_1, b_2, b_3)$ (with respect to the origin) with all components non zero? What rotation matrix would do the job?  What would be simpler to implement that just two coefficients?

Thanks.

Comment: hint, Dot product relates the angle between two vectors!

Comment: @Dietrich  Thanks for your comment. You are right, I want to do this in the plane.  I though there were tricks such as getting the 4 vertex of a paralellogram by adding the two sides (coefficients 1 and 1). The fact that the regular pentagon is so "regular" should imply clever tricks. Yes, I can solve equations. I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding vertices of regular polygon](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267646/finding-vertices-of-regular-polygon)

Comment: I see. The title looks like that you wanted to use linear algebra, and not clever tricks.

Comment: To me finding the other vertex of a parallelogram by adding the two vectors is pure linear algebra "clever" trick. Yes it looks simple but this simplicity make it clever. My motivation is that I am drawing figures using Tikz.  I know two vectors in 3D and want to find the other vertices using what I have and a couple of coefficients ($\alpha_3$ and $\alpha_4$).

Comment: @medley56  This is not "finding the vertices of a regular polygon. They can easily be found by solving $z^n-1=0$, with solutions $\text{e}^{i (2 . \pi/n)}$ That simple. Please check my answer and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

What are the coefficients required to finish a regular pentagon given
that two edges are known?

The answer is $1$ and the Golden ratio $\phi=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$. See the proof below:

These coefficients are two invariant of a pentagon. That is, no
matter its size or orientation the coefficients are the same.

If two edges are adjacent we can, without loss of generality, consider
that they have $O=(0,0,0)$ as their common vertex. Even more, 
since the coefficients that we are looking for are invariant, we
can consider the problem in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The five points of a pentagon are easily found by solving the
equation $x^5 + 1 = 0$.  These are given by:

\begin{eqnarray}
  x_1 &=& 1   \quad , \quad y_1 = 0 \\
      x_2 &=& \cos \theta   \quad , \quad y_2 = \sin \theta \\
      x_3 &=& \cos 2 \theta   \quad , \quad y_3 = \sin 2 \theta \\
      x_4 &=& \cos 3 \theta   \quad , \quad y_4 =  \sin 3 \theta \\
      x_5 &=& \cos 4 \theta   \quad , \quad y_5 =  \sin 4 \theta,
\end{eqnarray}
with $\theta=2 \pi/5=72^{\circ}$.
We want to push these solutions so that one of the vertices is 0.
At the moment the solutions are centered at 0. We can do this
by subtracting the vertex $(x_4,y_4)$ from all other vertices and getting
the coordinates (sorted in counter-clockwise order)

\begin{eqnarray}
   A &=& (1-\cos 3 \theta , - \sin 3 \theta) \\
      B &=& (\cos  \theta - \cos 3 \theta, \sin  \theta - \sin 3 \theta) \\
      C &=& (\cos 2 \theta - \cos 3 \theta, \sin 2 \theta - \sin 3 \theta) \\
      D &=& (0,0) \\
      E &=& (\cos 4 \theta - \cos 3 \theta, \sin 4 \theta - \sin 3 \theta) 
\end{eqnarray}

The figure below shows the pentagon before (left) and after (right) being pushed up to have the origin $O=(0,0)$ as one its vertices.

[image]

The vector equations to get to the vertex $A$ are
\begin{eqnarray}
   \alpha E + \beta C &=& A 
\end{eqnarray}
This is a simple system of two linear equations with two unkonwns.
The solutions are:

\begin{eqnarray*}
      \alpha &=& 2 \cos \theta - 1. \\
      \beta &=&  4\,\cos ^2\theta+2\,\cos \theta
    \end{eqnarray*}
Since for the pentagon $\theta=2 \pi/3=72^{\circ}$ the numerical evaluation for this is

\begin{eqnarray}
      \alpha &\approx& 1.618033988749895 \\
      \beta &=& 1.
 \end{eqnarray}

It is interesting, due to the symmetry of the problem that
the coefficients to get to $B$ are the same but in reverse order.
That is $\beta, \alpha$.

To test this I built the bottom layer of a dodecahedron which consists
 of three pentagons. We assume that we know the bottom vertex at $O=(0,0,0)$ 
 (the blue dot at the center) and
 three other vertices $A,B,C$ separated  (green color) $120^{\circ}$. The result of the
 computation of the other 6 vertices (brown color,no ball for indexed 2 vertices) are shown . They are computed
 from the following simple formula

\begin{eqnarray}
    D= \alpha A + \beta B \\
    D2= \beta A + \alpha B \\
    E= \alpha B + \beta C \\
    E2= \beta B + \alpha C \\
    F= \alpha C + \beta A \\
    F2= \beta C + \alpha A \\
 \end{eqnarray}

where $\alpha=1.618962432915921$ and $\beta=1$.
 The figure was computed using

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ
 using the equations above.

[image]

With the new vertices we can construct new ones by using recursively the same idea. For example:

\begin{eqnarray*}
      A_1 &=& A  + (F_2 -A) + \alpha (D-A) = F_2 + \alpha (D-A) \\  A_2 &=& A  + \phi (F_2 -A) + (D-A) = D + \alpha (F_2-A) \\
      B_1 &=& B  + (D_2 -B) + \alpha (E-B) = D_2 + \alpha (E-B) \\ B_2 &=& B  + \phi (D_2 - B) + (E-B) = E + \alpha (D_2-B) \\
      C_1 &=& C  + (E_2 -C) + \alpha (F-C) = E_2 + \alpha (F-C) \\ C_2 &=& C  + \phi (E_2 - C) + (F-C) = F + \alpha (E_2-C) \\
    \end{eqnarray*}

Provides 6 new vertices and three new faces. We show the figure for this, which corresponds to half of a dodecahedron.  The algorithm shown here becomes a simple algorithm without the need to compute complicated equations. Just adding vectors and scaling some of them with $\alpha$.
[image]

It is interesting to see that $\alpha$ is the Golden ratio
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoldenRatio.html
This suggest a pure geometrical proof:

In the first figure right frame (in red) figure, the segment that joints $C$ to $A$ is the vector
$A-C$, and it is parallel to the vector $E$. Then we know
that the ratio between a diagonal and the side of a pentagon is 
the Golden ratio $\phi$. That is
\begin{equation}
 \phi = \frac{|A - C|}{|E|}.
\end{equation}
So the scalar required to get to $A$ through $E$ is exactly the
Golden ratio $\phi$. Then
$A = \phi E + C$, from which the coefficients become
$\alpha=\phi=(1+\sqrt{5})/2 \approx1.61896243291592 $ and $\beta=1$.

For the construction of the whole dodecahedron visit this website:
[Cleverest construction of a dodecahedron / icosahedron?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632936/cleverest-construction-of-a-dodecahedron-icosahedron)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use matrix transformations, then this might help you:

Let $u_0=(0,0,0), u_1=(1,0,0), u_2=(1+\cos 72^{\circ}, \sin 72^{\circ},0)$,

$u_3=(1+\cos 72^{\circ}+\cos 144^{\circ}, \sin 72^{\circ}+\sin 144^{\circ},0)$,

$u_4=(1+\cos 72^{\circ}+\cos 144^{\circ}+\cos 216^{\circ}, \sin 72^{\circ}+\sin 144^{\circ}+\sin 216^{\circ},0)$

Then find the matrix $M$ such that $Mu_1=v_1$ and $Mu_2=v_2$